# Minimax form with a shared constraint

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, constraints

Let $f :\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a closed convex function and $\mathbf{a},  \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be given parameters. I have a problem that can be roughly represented as

$$ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}} - f(\theta) + \inf_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert \leq 1, \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert \leq 1} \{ \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{b} \ :  \ \mathbf{x}+ \mathbf{y} = \theta \cdot \mathbf{c} \}.$$

I would like to understand when I can change the order of $\inf$ and $\sup$, to obtain something like
$$\inf_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert \leq 1, \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert \leq 1} \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} + {\mathbf{y}}^\top \mathbf{b} + \sup_{\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}}\{-f(\theta) \ : \ \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} = \theta \cdot \mathbf{c}\}.$$

I understand that minimax theorem works when the constraints are separable and the objective is convex-concave, but here I have the other way around: The objective is separable and there is a single common **linear** constraint.

---

**Attempt**

I have tried to take the equality constraint to the objective via Lagrange duality to obtain
$$ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}} - f(\theta) + \sup_{\mathbf{\lambda}\in \mathbb{R}^n} \; \inf_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert \leq 1, \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert \leq 1} \{ \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{\lambda}^\top(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} - \theta \cdot \mathbf{c})\}.$$
I can now change the order of $\sup$ without loss of generality
$$ \sup_{\mathbf{\lambda}\in \mathbb{R}^n} \;  \sup_{\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}} - f(\theta) + \inf_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert \leq 1, \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert \leq 1} \{ \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{\lambda}^\top(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} - \theta \cdot \mathbf{c})\}.$$

Now I want to say something like *"if $\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} \neq \theta \cdot \mathbf{c}$ then the term $\mathbf{\lambda}^\top(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} - \theta \cdot \mathbf{c})$ is unbounded"* to somehow eliminate the Lagrange variables, but this is not possible since $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$ and $\theta$ are fixed upon seeing $\mathbf{\lambda}$.

---

**Omitted detail**

Note that, in an optimization problem, I have a constraint of form
$$ \sup_{\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbb{R}} - f(\theta) + \inf_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert \leq 1, \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert \leq 1} \{ \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{b} \ :  \ \mathbf{x}+ \mathbf{y} = \theta \cdot \mathbf{c} \} \leq 0 $$
where $\mathbf{c}$ is actually an optimization variable. So I will need to add some additional constraints on $\mathbf{c}$ so that eventually we have $\mathbf{x}+ \mathbf{y} = \theta \cdot \mathbf{c}$, but for that I need to characterise the optimal solution to the above form.

Comment: The infimum is over all $\bf x,y$ with norms $\le 1$, but you require $\mathbf x + \mathbf y = \theta\mathbf c$, with no particular resrictions on $\theta$ or $\bf c$. If $\|\theta\mathbf c\| > 2$ then the infimum will be taken over an empty set. And if you take the infimum of the empty set to be $+\infty$, then the supremum will be $+\infty$ unless $\bf c$ and $\Theta$ are chosen small enough that $\|\theta\mathbf c\| \le 2$ always.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you so much! This whole thing is constrained to be $\leq 0$ as a function of $\mathbf{c}$. I will make this clearer. Given that, I would like to understand whether constraining the first to $\leq 0$ as a function of $\mathbf{c}$ and doing the same to the second form are the same.

Comment: In the second form, most $\bf x,y$ are not going to add up to a multiple of $\bf c$, and thus the supremum will be taken over an empty set for them. Again, if one takes the supremum of an empty set to be $-\infty$, the infimum will *always* be $-\infty$, regardless of what restrictions are on $\Theta, \bf c$, so no, these two are not the same, and requiring them to be $\le 0$ is not the same restriction of $\bf c$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for taking the time. My question is poorly formulated. I will update it soon :)